# Closure overloading: is it possible to inspect the number of arguments a PHP closure has without executing it?

Tags: php, closures, overloading

### What I want to do

I want to inspect a closure (passed as a variable) to determine how many arguments it expects. Essentially, I want to overload a closure in the traditional sense, only by treating it differently.

```
function someMethod(Closure $callback) {
    $varA;
    $varB;
    $varC;
    if($callback->getNumArgs() == 3) {
        $callback($varA, $varB, $varC);
    }
    else {
        $callback($varC, $varA);
    }
}
```

*If this could be explained better, please let me know so it can be edited.*

### Background information

Depending on how many arguments the closure takes, I will adjust the way in which it's called. I need to do this to save expensive iterations through a loop.

#### Please note

- I am using PHP5.3
- **As a reminder, I do not want to execute the function and thus cannot use** `func_num_args`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With [Reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunction.php):

```
$ref = new ReflectionFunction(function($foo, $bar) {});
echo $ref->getNumberOfParameters(); // 2
```

Comment: Doh! I keep forgetting just how useful reflection is. Thanks :)